# Create a new UI for an Apache 2.0 software

Tags: copyright, apache-2.0, law

I'm creating a *fork* of a software distributed under the **Apache License 2.0**. This software has many components, one of them is its UI, where It's possible to find the creator's logo and other information about the developers.

Does the **APL2** permit that I **create a fork of this project**, and **develop my own UI**, in order to use **my logo and extended components**, and include all copyright/original developers' information in an **about** section of all other components that I use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is fully permitted to completely change the UI on a Apache 2.0-licensed project and to change the look&feel, logo's and where the attribution information is shown.